# Frequency response of ears when covered with hands

Tags: frequency, response

just as in the title. Anyone know if there is some info on this available. I know its very relative as to how you cover your ears, but an approximate/median graph would be useful to me.

Comment: this is a fairly clear cut physics question, best for http://physics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

You are applying a low pass filter - this tends to remove the middle frequencies in the spectrum a bit and the upper frequencies a lot. This is how I hear it anyway - try using a simple tone control to simulate the effect - probably just a fair amount of treble cut would do the same.

If you want to be really precise use a graphic equalizer that has a bypass button in it - bypass when your hands are across your ears and then remove your hands and activate the GE and adjust the individual controls to how you remember the sound - it shouldn't take more than 5 minutes to get some GE settings that are close to what your hands over your ears did.

Also when you've been on the phone to someone and they have incompletely put their hand across the microphone part of their handset - you still kind-of hear stuff but it is very muffled. Same with someone in another room - you can hear the bass stuff coming thru but the treble is lost along the way.

Answer (score 2):

[image: fir]

.

but that's just a guess, really.

Comment: I was thinking of a graph to be honest

Comment: oh you can always plot this one..

Comment: Nothing against joke answers, but this one is just a bit too blatant. A least make it consistent: this is not a frequency response but a discrete-time convolution kernel, that's equivalent only if we assume nothing nonlinear is introduced and if you start with the signal as PAM-sampled, which _could_ represent what you'll be hearing fine, but doesn't represent any of the physics actually going on.

Comment: it's a FIR filter function, in which you can come up with your coefficients (since it's "relative as to how you cover your ears")... this is meant to prompt a review of the original question, not to be the actual answer. of course it doesn't represent any of the physics. OP asked for representation (approximate graph), not physics ;]